# Load Preference EditText text and use it as filename

Tags: android, soundpool

So I have Preference EditText in my application and i Want to get that text from EditText and use it as filename in this code `String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), filename);` I've tried this :

```
   SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("EditText",0);
String zipStr = settings.getString("ime", "");  
sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), zipStr);
mSoundId = sp.load(path, 1);
```

And LogCat says : Sample 1 is not READY

using `String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), "SONG NAME");`  Finds song on external storage and soundpool uses it.. All i want is use EditText Text except "SONG NAME"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you confirmed that you have a file with the name that's stored in your pref?  Add `Log.d("TAG", "Path: " + path)` after your `String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), zipStr);` line and see what your path string actually  contains and that you actually have a file at that location with that name.

Comment: 11-06 15:57:59.169: D/ime(5688): Path: /mnt/sdcard

Comment: @KristijanZrno OK, so what files are there, and do any have a name that matches the string that's stored in the "ime" pref?  If not, then that's your problem. How are you putting files on the sdcard, and how are you assigning the prefs that represent the file names? You have to make sure that the names and locations you're saving and the actual names and locations of the files match, of course.